# DFS - find all paths where source is same as destination

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, depth-first-search

I want to find all the paths from source to destination using DFS where source is the same as the destination

E.g. Adjacency list for point A to B

```
0 - 1, 2
1 - 0, 3
2 - 0
3 - 1
```

So paths for 0 to 0 will be

```
0 1 0
0 2 0
0 1 3 1 0
```

Here is a working code that prints all the paths, but some are repeated and some are wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// This class represents a directed graph using adjacency list representation
class Graph {
    private:
        // No. of vertices
        int V;

        // Pointer to an array containing adjacency lists
        list<int> *adj;

        // A function used by DFS
        void DFSUtil(int v, int visited[], vector<int> &vec, int s, int d);

    public:
        // Constructor
        Graph(int V);

        // function to add an edge to graph
        void addEdge(int v, int w);

        // prints DFS traversal of the complete graph
        void DFS();
};

Graph::Graph(int V) {
    this->V = V;
    this->adj = new list<int>[V];
}

void Graph::addEdge(int v, int w) {
    // Add w to v’s list
    adj[v].push_back(w);
    adj[w].push_back(v);
}

Graph construct_graph() {
    Graph g(4);
    g.addEdge(0, 1);
    g.addEdge(1, 3);
    g.addEdge(0, 2);
    return g;
}

void Graph::DFSUtil(int v, int visited[], vector<int> &paths, int s, int d) {

    // Increase visited count of current node and add it to path
    visited[v]++;
    paths.push_back(v);

    if((v == d) && (visited[s] == 2) && (paths.size() > 1)){
        cout << "Path: ";
        for(int i = 0; i < paths.size(); i++) {
            cout << paths[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;

    } else {
        // Recur for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex
        list<int>::iterator i;
        for(i = adj[v].begin(); i != adj[v].end(); ++i) {
            if(visited[*i] < 2) {
                DFSUtil(*i, visited, paths, s, d);
            }
        }
    }

    if(paths.size() > 1) {
        visited[v]--;
        paths.pop_back();
    }
}

// The function to do DFS traversal. It uses recursive DFSUtil()
void Graph::DFS() {
    // Mark all the vertices as not visited
    int *visited = new int[V];
    for(int i = 0; i < V; i++) {
        visited[i] = 0;
    }

    // store potential path here till destination is reached
    vector<int> paths;

    // Call the recursive helper function to print DFS traversal
    // starting from all vertices one by one
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) {
        if (visited[i] < 2) {
            DFSUtil(i, visited, paths, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    // construct graph
    // 0 ----- 1
    // |       |
    // |       |
    // 2       3

    Graph g = construct_graph();

    // Time: O(V + E), Space: O(V^2)
    g.DFS();
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

This is my output:

```
Path: 0 1 0
Path: 0 1 3 1 0
Path: 0 2 0
Path: 0 1 0
Path: 0 1 3 1 0
Path: 0 2 0
Path: 0 3 1 0
Path: 0 3 1 3 1 0
```

---

---

This is what i am expecting:

```
Path: 0 1 0
Path: 0 1 3 1 0
Path: 0 2 0
```

---

Comment: Note that a DFS will find an infinite number of solutions of the form 0 1 3 1 3 1 3 1 3 1 3 1 0

Comment: *This is what i am expecting:* -- And what do programmers do when something is not correct in their program?  Have you used your debugger?

Comment: Sanity/style: C++ is not Java, you should generally find a way to *avoid* saying `new` (and thus `delete`). In this case, use a `std::vector<std::list<int>>` instead of a raw pointer with count. Currently, you're leaking memory in the destructor and have a bogus copy-constructor.

Comment: Your `Graph` class is full of memory leaks.  Also, if you're using `std::vector` already, why didn't you use it here? `this->adj = new list<int>[V];` -- This could have been `std::vector<list<int>> adj;` then  initialize the vector using `Graph(int V) : adj(V) { }`